# jscs --fix not working as I would expect it

Tags: node.js, jscs

I'm trying to use jscs --preset=airbnb --fix to help with my formatting. I'm trying it on a line which is over 100 characters like

`router.post('/api/v1/words/dailyTotals/', middleware.requireAuthentication,  controllers.dailyTotal.create);`

Where it's not splitting it as I would expect it. Is this normal?

Comment: Where would you expect it to split. Maybe add output received versus expected? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? None of us can help you unless I have something to work with, in particular a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A great way to explain this is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Also, do check out the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Hi @impinball your right. I just pushed up a sample project https://github.com/foobar8675/foo/tree/master where in that directory, i tried typing jscs routes/ --fix  .  i can understand if it's because jscs doesn't know how to split the line, I just wanted to know if it was that or if i was missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure JSCS can fix everything, especially lines that are too long (a fix could theoretically break other rules). Automatic fixing of indentation/etc. is a very tricky thing to pull off.

Comment: @impinball that totally makes sense. i didn't see any documentation on the limitations so wanted to make sure i was not doing something wrong. if you wanted to put your comment in as the answer, i can mark it as the correct one.